# Как организовать поиск записи по названию тега в laravel?

Tags: php, алгоритм, laravel, laravel-5.6

У каждой записи есть свои теги, нужно организовать показ всех записей, в которых присутствует такой тег. Я пробовал это сделать, но потерялся на составлении запроса в базу данных. Как бы вы посоветовали реализовать такое?

[image: Таблицы]

[image: Связующая таблица]

[image: Таблица категорий]

[image: Модель User]

[image: Модель записи Rhyme]

[image: Модель категории]

Comment: Если бы базу показали и то что вы пробовали - было бы замечательно

Comment: что конкретно показать?

Comment: Структуру таблиц, модели, как у вас устроены записи, теги, как они связаны друг с другом.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно вывести все сущности `Rhymes` в которых встречается категория, то просто можно воспользоватся методом `whereHas`:

```
$rhymes = Rhyme::whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', 'тест');
})->get();
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!